# $\int_0^1 f(x)e^{nx} \, dx=0$ for all $n \in \Bbb N\cup{\{0\}}$ implies $f(x) = 0$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, weierstrass-approximation

$f$ is a continuous real valued function $f: [0,1] \to\mathbb R$ and
$\int_0^1 f(x)e^{nx} \, dx=0$ $\forall n \in N\cup{\{0\}} \implies f(x) = 0$ on the interval $[0,1]$

I am trying to prove this result. I have tried using Stone-Weirestrass with both polynomials and exponential functions; however, I cannot seem to prove it this way. Can someone offer a hint or suggestion.

Comment: Use Stone-Weierstrass theorem. Notice that $\{1,e^x\}$ separates points of $[0,1]$; hence the collection of polynomials on $e^x$ are dense in $\mathcal{C}([0,1])$ equipped with the uniform topology. From there, you get that $\int^1_0f(x)p(x)\,dx=0$ for all continuous functions on $[0,1]$ (chose a sequence of polynomials in $e^x$ that converge to $p$). The rest follows from density of $C([0,1])$ in $L_1([0,1])$, for then $\mathbb{1}_{(a,b]}$ can be approximated in $L_1$ ny functions in $C([0,1])$.

Comment: @OliverDiaz Thank you. We didn't really cover most of what you said in lecture. Is there an alternate way?

Comment: @JakeFremman: Ok, if you understood up to the point that $\inf^1_0f(x)p(x)\,dx=0$ for all $p\in C([0,1])$ that you are basically done, for then, you can take $p=f$ to get $\int^1_0f^1=0$. As you know, a continuous function $g$ that is nonnegative and integrates to zero over an interval, say $[0,1]$, must be zero (otherwise, you can choose a point $x_0$ where $g(x_0)>0$. Then in a small neighborhood $V\subset[0,1]$ of $x_0$ $g>0$ and so $0<\int_V g\leq \int^1_0g=0$ contradiction!

Comment: @OliverDiaz Thank you I follow somewhat. did you mean $\int_{0}^{1}f^2=0$? Because then I follow mostly.

Comment: @OliverDiaz If you could explain how you got the $\int_{0}^{1}f(x)*p(x)dx=0$ for all continuous functions a bit more that would be helpful.

Comment: Sure, the argument I outlined in my comments allow you to show that $f^2=0$ whence you conclude that $f=0$.

Comment: @OliverDiaz Yes that makes sense. If you could provide a little more explaination on the construction of $p(x)$, I'd be very appreciative.

Comment: @OliverDiaz I had the eureka moment. I understand your argument completely. I am going to prove it differently but thanks alot!

Comment: @JakeFreeman Please do not use titles consisting only of math expressions; these are discouraged for technical reasons -- see the [guidelines for good use of $\rm\LaTeX$ in question titles](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9730).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint:

1. The function $x\mapsto e^x$ separates points of $[0,1]$. Hence, the collection of polynomials $\mathcal{P}$ on $e^x$ (including constants) form a dense set in $C([0,1])$ under the uniform norm.
2. The conditions of the problem show that $\int^1_0 fp=0$ for any $p\in\mathcal{P}$. For any $g\in C([0,1])$ choose a sequence of polynomials $p_n\in\mathcal{P}$ that coverage to $g$ uniformly. Then
   $$\Big|\int^1_0fg\Big|=\Big|\int^1_0fp_n-fg\Big|\leq\int^1_0|f||g-p_n|dx\leq \|f\|_u\|g-p_n\|_u\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}0$$
   Which means that $\int^1_0fg=0$ for all $g\in C([0,1])$.
3. Apply (2) to $g=f$ to conclude that $\int^1_0f^2=0$.
4. Conclude that $f^2=0$. Suppose $f^2(x_0)>0 $ for some $x)\in[0,1]$. By continuity chose a small subinterval $V$ containing $x_0$ where $f^2>0$. Then $0<\int_Vf^2\leq \int^1_0 f^2=0$ contradiction!

See if you can fill in all the details.

Comment: Why not just choose polynomials $p_n$ such that $p_n(e^x)\to f$ uniformly? Then we get $\int_0^1f^2=0$ faster.

Comment: @zhw. Sure!  But first I want to make the point that the Stone-Weierstras theorem gives a little more. Indeed, I could have been more economic in my arguments.

Answer (score 2):

We can do this with just the Weierstrass theorem and a change of variables. In the given integrals, let $x=\ln y.$ Then we see

$$\int_1^e f(\ln y)y^{n-1}\,dy = 0,\,n=0,1,\dots.$$

It follows that $\int_1^e f(\ln y)p(y)\,dy = 0$ for every polynomial $p.$ By Weierstrass, there is a sequnce $p_n$ of polynomials that converge to $f(\ln y)$ uniformly on $[1,e].$ In the usual way we then obtain

$$\int_1^e (f(\ln y))^2\,dy=0.$$

This implies $f(\ln y)\equiv 0.$ Hence $f\equiv 0.$